# Rotating an Android View

Tags: android, animation, view, canvas, rotation

I want to rotate an Android View with API level 8.  For example, I want to rotate an EditText by 90 degrees so that when the user enters text into a left justified EditText, the first character is at the bottom (rotated 90 degrees) and subsequent characters are entered upwards.

I first tried using an animation with duration of 0, but you still see the field rotate.  Unfortunately, this is a non-starter.  If I could find a way to hide the animation completely, this method looks to be the simplest.

I then tried rotating the canvas in onDraw which works great for square Views but not so great for ones that aren't square (and I don't control the dimensions of the EditText).  I tried various attempts at clipping and translating the canvas, but while I could get the cursor to come into view at the start of text input, it would do weird things once somebody started entering more content (usually the content would disappear out of view).

I also tried making the View square in onMeasure, then rotating the canvas in onDraw, then putting the View dimensions back in a subsequent onMeasure.  The first two steps worked great.  But the third step produced similar results as described above: things looked ok until the user started entering more text at which point the field text did strange things (usually disappearing).

Has anybody been able to successfully rotate a non-square Android View (an EditText for example) without animation, and with API level 8 or lower?

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a pretty good amount of time trying to rotate a view exactly on API level 8 and I think it's impossible to make it work properly. FYI, it doesn't work correctly on android 3.2 either although there's a `setRotation(int angle)` method in the View class. This won't work correctly at all for VideoView for example.

P.S back then it seemed that I've managed to make the rotation thing work for anything other than VideoView though. Have you overriden the `onTouchEvent` method? If you have not your view won't be receiving the touch event since rotating the canvas will just make the view draw rotated but it will still receive the touch events in its old area. You have to manually apply rotation matrix to the touch event coordinates in order to offset them to the proper location.